# How to read the current url of the page in a modal on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that opens a modal on click. That modal displays a page from a different file's url on the server. However, when I moved it from localhost to stage, the url of that file changed and the modal cannot read that file anymore.

So I have been trying to figure out a way to have it automatically know the updated url of that file instead of me putting in the actual url. I have tried using window.location.href but that opens the page the button is located on in the modal instead of opening the different file in the modal.

```
<script>
    btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      let url = "http://localhost:1111/hello";
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4){
          if (request.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("modal_text").innerHTML = request.responseText;
          } else {
            //handle error
          }
        }

      };

      request.open('GET', url);
      request.send();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a root relative url:

```
let url = "/hello";
```

The browser will know to use same protocol, host and port from current `location`